# How to calculate the area of a generalized ellipse in form $\frac{|x|^c}{a^c} + \frac{|y|^c}{b^c} = 1$?

Tags: geometry, area

I have a generalized ellipse (ref. Eq(1) in Athanassoula, et al. ["The shape of bars in early-type barred galaxies." (via harvard.edu)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990MNRAS.245..130A/abstract) (1990) )
$$
\frac{|x|^c}{a^c} + \frac{|y|^c}{b^c} = 1
$$
where $a$, $b$ are semi-axis, and $c$ a free parameter in a range $(0,4)$, which is enough for me in my problem; when $c=2$, it returns to normal ellipse.

How to calculate its area?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you find the area with integration with cartesian coordinates or polar coordinates... Also, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Area

Comment: Unfortunately, the article you mention is not accessible for "mortals"...

Answer (score 2):

The cartesian version of the equation of your function is

$$y=\pm b\left(1-\dfrac{|x|^c}{a^c}\right)^{1/c}$$

which represents in fact two functions (resp. the upper and lower parts of the curve according to the choice between signs $+$ or $-$).

But, due to the symmetry of the curve with respect to $x$ and $y$ axes (see figure below), it is sufficient to consider the $+$ case on its $[0,a]$ part, and compute the quarter of this area (situated in the first quadrant) by the following integral :

$$b\int_{x=0}^{a}\left(1-\dfrac{x^c}{a^c}\right)^{1/c}dx=ab\int_{X=0}^{1}\left(1-X^c\right)^{1/c}dX=ab\dfrac{\Gamma(1+\tfrac1c)^2}{\Gamma(1+\tfrac2c)}\tag{1}$$

the second part resulting from the change of variable $X:=\dfrac{x}{a}$, the last part being obtained using Wolfram Alpha (in fact, @Will Jagy has given in a comment below a reference where this result is proved).

with, of course, a final multiplication by $4$.

In the particular case $c=2$ (ordinary ellipse), (1) becomes:

$$ab\dfrac{\Gamma(\tfrac32)^2}{\Gamma(2)}=ab\dfrac{(\tfrac12\Gamma(\tfrac12))^2}{1}=ab\tfrac14 (\sqrt{\pi})^2=ab\tfrac{\pi}{4}$$

as awaited for the quarter of the area of an ellipse with semiaxes $a$ and $b$.

[image]

*Fig. 1: For $a=3$ and $b=2$. Cases $c=0.5$ (starlike), $c=1$ (lozenge) ... to $c=4$ (almost rectangular).*

Comment: There is not the symmetry you think! Regards.

Comment: @Piquito I am fairly certain of the central symmetry of this generalized ellipse...

Comment: With $c=2.2$, for example, the graph of the curve looks like an elliptic curve without an oval. (seems for example to $x^3+y^3=64$ according Desmos)

Comment: Jean, there is a method of Dirichlet  that gives this; it is in the book by Watson and Whittaker. The conclusion, a fairly simple integral is on pages 191-192 of the first edition, fairly complete. I have the fourth edition, it is just an exercise on page 258, although enough detail is probably given  https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis/FSAWAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: With $ a,b,c, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, p,q,r > 0$

$$  I = \int \int \int f\left(   \left(\frac{x}{a}  \right)^\alpha +   \left(\frac{y}{b}  \right)^\beta +  \left(\frac{z}{c}  \right)^\gamma \right) x^{p-1}  y^{q-1} z^{r-1} dx dy dz  $$
in the region
$$ x,y,z \geq 0  \; , \; \; \; \; \left(\frac{x}{a}  \right)^\alpha +   \left(\frac{y}{b}  \right)^\beta +  \left(\frac{z}{c}  \right)^\gamma \leq 1 $$

Comment: $$  I = \frac{a^p b^q c^r}{\alpha \beta \gamma} \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{q}{\beta} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{r}{\gamma} \right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{p}{\alpha} + \frac{q}{\beta} + \frac{r}{\gamma}  \right)} \int_0^1 f(\xi) \xi^{\frac{p}{\alpha} + \frac{q}{\beta} + \frac{r}{\gamma} - 1} d \xi $$

Comment: @Piquito No in fact, this curve isn't weird at all, it's more and more rectangular ! Therefore, my method is good. Case $c=2.2$ for example is just a little different from an ordinary ellipse.

Comment: @Will Jagy : Thanks, Will, I am going to have a look at this still excellent reference almost one century old...

Comment: @Jean Marie: Good for you, dear professor if I am wrong. However for $(x/3)^c+(y/5 )^c=1$ the corresponding curve for the two values $c=2.2$ and $c^=1.96$ looks like an elliptic curve. Regards.

Comment: it is a symmetric case, because in the original definition, you have |x| and |y|, you may look the reference paper, Fig. 1

Comment: I enjoyed professor Jean Marie is right!

Comment: Hi Jean-Marie ! How would you write the perimeter or the arclength ? This is not a joke. Cheers and take care.

Comment: Hi Claude! This must be another "pair of sleeves" (pretty certain that a non-french speaking person can't understand the joke).

Comment: one page said that sleeves were once detachable and one could trade the current sleeves for a different pair.  " This French phrase is based on the fact that sleeves used to be separate articles of dress, which could be worn at will with any garment."   There were some pictures...  https://www.frenchlearner.com/expressions/cest-une-autre-paire-de-manches/  and   https://wordhistories.net/2017/03/13/another-pair-of-shoes/

Comment: @Will Jagy Wow ! Cudos at the way you have catched it. In fact, I didn't know the explanation of the expression... Languages are fascinating...

Comment: @JeanMarie the pictures suggest that the sleeves were small, bands of cloth  to go around the wrist. Decorative rather than functional, and for the gowns of women of the nobility. Hundreds of years ago